# hadoop-aws and aws-java-sdk versions compatible for Spark 2.3

Tags: java, scala, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop

I use Spark 2.3.0 and Scala 2.11.8

What are the compatible versions of the following libraries?:

hadoop-aws

aws-java-sdk

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These all are published to maven central so first check which hadoop version [spark 2.3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11/2.3.0) depends on. It says [`hadoop-client 2.6.5`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-client/2.6.5). Luckily hadoop-aws follows the same versioning so [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-aws/2.6.5) is the corresponding aws dependency. Finally we can see that `hadoop-aws 2.6.5` depends on [`aws-java-sdk 1.7.4`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/1.7.4).

Comment: `Luckily hadoop-aws follows the same versioning`, where can we find more information on this statement?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using EMR, the relevant versions can be found on the EMR Cluster Summary tab of the AWS UI, for example:

[image: EMR and Hadoop versions]

Versions of software compatible with each version of EMR can also be seen at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-release-5x.html.

Comment: I don't use EMR. I run Spark locally in InteliJ IDE.

Comment: Then what are you using AWS for?